# Deploying community from Sandbox to production

Tags: community, deployment, metadata, change-set

I have created a community in my sandbox and want to deploy it to the production org. Please suggest what is the best way to achieve. Any detailed documentation around steps would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The deployment of communities if they are based on a Template its little different than normally how you deploy them .

Here are some of key learnings

1. Deploy all metadata as you normally do ,but pay special attention to below as these are community specific

   i. SiteDotCom

   ii. Network

   iii. Communities_Shared_Document_Folder

   iv. CustomSite

   v. Topic_Shared_Document_Folder

Make sure to include all those in your package.xml and don't miss any of them as they are inter related

2. For new communities note that you also need "AuraBundle" deployed if you have lightning components

Complete the deployment via ANT or force.com migration tool

3. Use import mechanism from the Site assets. There is a [blogpost](https://blogs.perficient.com/salesforce/2015/12/22/deploy-community-builder-templates-in-3-simple-steps/) on how to do this. Carry this step only after you deploy all metadata as mentioned in step 1 and 2
4. There is a small bug with managed Topics currently, so all Featured and Navigational Topic I would recommend to create manually or use data loader.(I guess they still working on this to fix the issues)

If you use Force.com migration tool with latest jar that's the best bet.

Comment: Not sure where can I find Communities_Shared_Document_Folder, CustomSite, Topic_Shared_Document_Folder to add them in change set?

Answer (score 1):

If your using Eclipse it is possible to get the basic config of your Community and deploy it with the migration tool (along with meta), but for that you will have to create the community on each new environment prior to deploying the community meta data to it.